# Block scope variable gets value set in anonymous function within block but this value is not available outside the function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update the value of `start` inside an anonymous function contained within the block but this does not seem to be happening.

When I declare a variable with `let`, I imagined that this variable would be block scoped and it's value could be updated by anonymous functions within the block.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function getStartTime(Id) {
  let start = '';
  let bQuery = "select StartTime from database.table where Id=?";
  dbService.executeDQuery(bQuery, Id, function (error, rs_bs) {
    if (error) {
      next(error);
      return;
    }
    
    start = JSON.stringify(rs_bs[0]["StartTime"]);
    
    console.log("start in = " + start); //shows the correct value
  });
  
  console.log("start out = " + start); //this is empty
  
  return start; //nothing returned
}
```

Comment: i think `dbService.executeDQuery` async function, right?

Comment: It's not a scope problem. It's a timing problem. Everything outside the callback happens before everything inside the callback. Remember, the inner function will be called **in the future** by the `executeDBquery` function

Comment: @BesufkadMenji - yes, it is